# Lighting Experience Related list not updated when "New" is overridden to use a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, lightning-ready

This question is pretty much the same as [related list not getting updated in Salesforce Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150724/related-list-not-getting-updated-in-salesforce-lightning) from 2 years ago. That doesn't have an accepted answer and has a comment that suggests one answer may not work.

(Note that our aim is to be [Lightning Ready](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Lightning_Ready) for now rather than to do a rewrite of a lot of Visualforce in Lightning Components. One reason is that we have a substantial installed base who want to continue working in Classic.)

The override of the "New" action to use a Visualforce page works in Lightning Experience and returns to the parent page correctly. But **the "Related" list is not updated** to include the newly created object. Without the override, the platform correctly refreshes the "Related" list.

Does anyone have a reliable solution to this problem? Do I need to start thinking about [firing Lightning Events](http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2016/02/lightning-events-via-visualforce.html) from the Visualforce pages?

**PS**

Some more Googling has led me to this known issue [Data updates are not reflected in UI after a Visualforce+Apex update in Lightning Experience](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU&title=data-not-updated-in-ui-after-an-apex-update-in-lightning-experience) reported by 530 users and more than 6 months old. That relates to the details not the related list, but a fix may address both. For now though, any workarounds?

Comment: I have a came out with the same problem, what I have done is render my button based on the different theme and used Sforce.one.back(true) and Sforce.navigatetosobject together oncomplete. It makes me sure to give the refreshed view always.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but we had come across a similar situation, which made to a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCpKQAU), while overriding "Edit" button on a record. And that we were using `force:navigateToSObject` to navigate back to the record. I would imagine this to be something similar to that.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I'd recommend this approach, but I ended up making a super simple Lightning component that I put on the record page that calls `e.force:refreshView` on component load. This forces a reload of the cache of the page on load, and makes sure it is up-to-date after any Visualforce pages have done some updates.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.doInit}" label="Refresh" title="Refresh"/>
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: How do you avoid infinite regress? Doesn't `refreshView` force everything including the Lightning components on the record page to reload?

Comment: No, it only refreshes once.

Comment: I like the solution mostly. However, when I tried it verbatim just now, the refresh did not take. However, if you include a window.timeout () [500 ms works for me] in doInit, the refresh happens.