# Pagereference Return is getting cached and not rendering latest UI until refresh

Tags: visualforce, controller, standardcontroller, standardsetcontroller, caching

I have a requirement where we perform "Mass delete" for records in one of the related list (Custom object called Recipient__c) from the parent object (Parent Object called FundCommunication__c).

[image: It looks like above one]

My VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Recipient__c" extensions="MassDeleteRecipientscontroller" recordSetVar="Documents">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:form rendered="{!NOT(hasErrors)}">
        <apex:outputText value="Are you certain you want to delete these Recipients?" />
        <p style="font-size:18px;"/>
        <br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Ok" action="{!deleteSelectedRecipient}" rendered="{!showOkButton}"/>
        <apex:commandbutton action="{!redirectToRecord}" style="margin-left:30%;" value="Back to Fund communication" rendered="{!showReturnButton}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

After I Click on `'Ok'`, the selected records are deleted. After that If I click on `'Back to fund communication button'`, the page is getting navigated back to the Fund Communication record, but the related list for which the records are deleted are not getting updated until I refresh. (The records which are deleted are still appearing). Not sure if this a caching issue.

Below is my controller:

```
public class MassDeleteRecipientscontroller {
    
    public static String EMPTY_SELECTION = 'No Recipients selected.';
    public static String DELETE_SUCCESS = 'Recipients were deleted successfully.';
    
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController;
    private List<Recipient__c> selectedRecipients;
    public Boolean hasErrors {get; set;}
    private Id fundCommunicationId;
    public Boolean showOkButton {get; set;}
    public Boolean showReturnButton {get; set;}
    
    public MassDeleteRecipientscontroller(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController) {
        this.hasErrors = false;
        this.standardSetController = standardSetController;
        this.selectedRecipients = standardSetController.getSelected();
        this.showOkButton = true;
        Id RecipientId = this.selectedRecipients[0].Id;
        if (selectedRecipients.isEmpty()) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING, EMPTY_SELECTION));
            this.hasErrors = true;
        }
        List<Recipient__c> recipientList = [SELECT Id, fund_communication__r.Id FROM Recipient__c where Id =: RecipientId];
        this.fundCommunicationId = recipientList[0].fund_communication__r.Id;
        system.debug('Fund communication id is '+this.fundCommunicationId);
    }
    
    public PageReference deleteSelectedRecipient() {
        System.debug('Deleting: ' + this.selectedRecipients);
        try{
        delete this.selectedRecipients;
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, DELETE_SUCCESS));
            showOkButton = false;
            showReturnButton = true;
        }
        catch(exception e){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public pageReference redirectToRecord(){
        //Id RoundDetailId = this.standardController.getId();
       PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + fundCommunicationId);
       pageRef.setRedirect(true);
       return pageRef;
    }
}
```

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150724/related-list-not-getting-updated-in-salesforce-lightning